# How to achieve exact background color of UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an exact design of the controls with exact colours by the designer who insists on using colours up to a point. The problem with iOS7 though, that tint messes things up and I am unable to find a solution for that.
For example, setting background colour to RGB:(00,199,242) gives me RGB:(24,187,238).

Is it possible to achieve exact background colour without reverting to using background image?

Comment: Try setting the background image to `[UIImage image]`, maybe it gets rid of that tint.

Comment: How are you setting the color and how are you measuring the resulting color? Also, what is the superview of the button?

Comment: @Levi, I cannot use image, because the button has its own image/icon on it.

Comment: @Jorge, I am measuring the color using two ways: eyes :) and DigitalColor Meter app on the development machine using simulator.

Comment: Could you post a sample of what color you need and how it is being rendered currently?

Comment: @UrK buttons do have the possibility to add background images in addition to the standard image. Also, the Mac uses color management to map colors between devices, I am not sure how DigitalColorMeter works in that respect, but be sure to use sRGB.

Comment: The colors: both expected and actual are in the question. I'm setting the color to RGB:(00,199,242) and getting RGB:(24,187,238). This can be seen with naked eye even without the color meter. Setting background image solves the issue, but this kind of misses the point of background color for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the RGB to the designer. Obiouvsly the color on device is different than on Photoshop.

When I try to get RGB from mockup by myself with `Digital Color Meter`, the color I get on device is too much different from rather than the mockup.

Comment: I have the exact colour from the designer. This is not what I get on the screen of the device/simulator due to tint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIColor method

```
colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha
```

but it accepts values between 0 and one so you need to divide it by 255, try:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255 green:199/255 blue:242/255 alpha:1];
```

Comment: Setting the color this way does not give the exact color value due to iOS7 tint featured. The color is slightly off as described in the original question.

Comment: BTW, I think you have do divide by 256, not by 255.

Comment: @UrK, you have to divide it by 255, obviously. it is just elemetary maths, not rocket science.

Comment: I think this is because you have RGB colour. My artworker provide me RGBA colour format and I divide it by 255 as in my answer above and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It is really 255, not 256. Forgot that max value of the color is 0xff, not 0x100. :)